# Guest OS can't detect increased VirtualBox disk size

Tags: debian, virtualbox, vdi

I have resized my vdi file through *Virtual Media Manager* from 32 to 64G, but when I run `lsblk` there are no changes to the disk whatsoever, when it should have the extra 32G of unpartitioned space.

The guest OS I'm using is Debian 10. I made sure to make a snapshot of the VM so it can't be that I messed up the disk "internally".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint here for what's wrong is that a snapshot was created.

When you resize the vdi, you shouldn't just select the name of the machine, but expand it until you get the snapshot you are currently working on, and expand that instead.

So instead of the name it should be a serial number. You can figure out which one it is by hovering over it, which should display the name.